# Can we rename the "Aldryn" tag to "Divio"?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

There are a number of questions that use the [aldryn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aldryn) tag.

*Aldryn* is now (and has been for some time) called *Divio Cloud* (or just *Divio*), even though the name *Aldryn* persists in some packages for historical reasons.

I suggest that the tag simply be renamed to *Divio*.

Comment: Seems reasonable. I have to wonder, though, why everyone asking questions about it continues to call it Aldryn? Surely someone would have created a [divio] tag by now, right? But they haven't.

Comment: @CodyGray I tried to!

Comment: I just looked at the 15 newest [aldryn] questions, and 10/15 use "Aldryn" as part of the question title or within the first two lines of the question. Apparently people are still used to using that term, so I don't know if it makes sense to just remove aldryn, since people might then start looking for it. Maybe a tag synonym that redirects you from aldryn to divio would be best in this case.

Comment: Also, there is no tag wiki or guidance yet...

Comment: @CodyGray My guess would be tutorials & co. that haven't been updated. I mean, just look at PHP's `mysql_*` APIs. They've been deprecated in mid 2013 and removed in late 2015, yet every other question tagged `[php][mysql]` still uses them...

Comment: Maybe it's better to create [tag:divio] and synonymise [tag:aldryn] to that, especially if people are still using the old name.

Comment: @DanieleProcida May I suggest you propose a brief wiki? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/117623) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/129359). Given that the tag is used on only 31 questions at the moment, a synonym can only be created by a moderator, I think. The [normal voting procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) won't work.

Comment: @CodyGray Then again, [15 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Baldryn%5D+divio) *mention* Divio. A quick check tells me most askers simply don't have the privilege to create a tag (yet).

Answer (score 6):

I wasn't sure about this initally. As mentioned in the comments by myself and others, it gave me some degree of pause that everyone has been referring to it as Aldryn, rather than Divio, and that nobody has managed to create a [divio] tag, even by accident from using the correct name.

The arguments were made that this is most likely because most people asking questions about this do not yet have the tag-creation privilege, and because most of the literature available continues to use the old name. That makes sense.

I looked into this, and it seems that the vendor themselves is clearly using the name Divio, so our standard protocols for tag naming would mandate that we, too, use the tag name [divio]. So, despite not having any real domain knowledge, it seemed to me that this is indeed the right thing to do, and I went ahead and made it so.

If this is *not* correct, and you believe that I've errored here, it is easy enough to undo. Please leave me a comment citing your objection.

As far as people continuing to use the wrong name and not being able to find the information, that is not a problem. Our tag synonym system will take care of that. If you type in [aldryn], you will automatically be directed to the [divio] tag. Magic.

I'd also echo the suggestion in the comments: **if you are able, please submit a tag wiki!**